# Did Digitizing tools last update remove polygon cutting?

Tags: polygon, qgis-plugins, digitizing, tools

In a previous project i used the Digitizing Tools plugin to cut polygons from other polygons.
But it seems that with a new update that feature is removed? I can't seem to use the most of the buttons.
Any advise on a different plugin that will easily help me cut polygons from other polygons?
Especially when its difficult with underlying polygons that get completely covered by the polygon on top, in the same layer.
I am not a professional with QGis so I hope there is an easy fix for this.

To specify; I use QGIS Desktop 3.8.0 (Zanzibar) with GRASS 7.6.1.
The Digitizing Tools plugin is updated to the latest version 1.5.1

Here is an image to shhow how i can't use the tool dispite being in editing mode for the layer.
[image]

Comment: Please specify, which QGIS version and which toolbar you're talking about. Have you made sure, the layer is in editing mode?

Comment: I just added the specifications. And yes, the layer was definitely in editing mode

Comment: Can you specify how the native `advanced digitizing toolbar` doesn't suite your needs?

Comment: I added a picture that will hopefully show what i mean. The commands are in dutch though. The digitizing tools plug in is all in grey, showing that i can't use them. The native toolbar doesn't have a command that will let me cut a polygon with another polygon. It will only let me split by drawing a line myself.